# Tuning Primer - No Valid Socket File

Tags: sockets, cygwin, performance, mysql

I am trying to run Tuning Primer using Cygwin on my Windows 7 computer to check some of my databases.

Whenever I try to run it, It gives me the following error:

```
No valid socket file "" found!
/cygdrive/c/Users/MID-PC/Downloads/tuning-primer.sh: line 109: tput: comando não encontrado
The mysqld process is not running or it is installed in a custom location.
/cygdrive/c/Users/MID-PC/Downloads/tuning-primer.sh: line 109: tput: comando não encontrado
If you are sure mysqld is running, execute script in "prompt" mode or set
/cygdrive/c/Users/MID-PC/Downloads/tuning-primer.sh: line 109: tput: comando não encontrado
the socket= variable at the top of this script
/cygdrive/c/Users/MID-PC/Downloads/tuning-primer.sh: line 109: tput: comando não encontrado
```

Any Idea of how can I manually set this socket?
(Yes, I do have MySQL running on this machine)